# Are there lionfish on the caribbean coasts of Costa Rica? Is it safe to snorkel there?

Tags: diving, caribbean, costa-rica

A few weeks ago we had the opportunity to snorkel in Cahuita National Park in Costa Rica.

The experience was great because of the coral reef there, but at some point of the activity I saw what I think it was a lionfish.

I was several minutes staring at that fish because it was really striking. At that moment I did not know about the name or the riskiness of it, but after the diving a woman of the group mentioned that. She explained the danger of this species due to its venomous spines.

I have been looking at some pictures and I am pretty sure that [this fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pterois_antennata) is what I saw that day.

How safe is to snorkel there then? How common are nonlethal lionfish stings? How common are lethal lionfish stings?

Answer (score 5):

Lionfish are a highly invasive species and I've seen them a lot when diving or snorkeling. Often a dive master or guide will spear them just to reduce population and slow down the spread. Their spikes are indeed venomous but they are not aggressive. As long as you keep some reasonable distance you are perfectly safe. Stings are rare and mostly accidental. Don't step on one or try catch them by hand !

https://www.healthline.com/health/lionfish-sting#about